# problem in creating thumb picture in php

Tags: php

I am using following function to create thumb picture in php

```
function createThumbnail($img,$imgPath,$newPath,$newWidth,$newHeight,$quality)
{
    $path=$imgPath."/".$img;
    echo $path;
    $original = imagecreatefromjpeg($path);

    if($original)
    {
        echo "occur1";
        list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize("$imgPath/$img");
        $tempImg = imagecreatetruecolor($newWidth, $newHeight) or die("Cant create temp image");
        imagecopyresized($tempImg, $original, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newWidth, $newHeight, $width, $height)        or die("Cant resize copy");
        imagejpeg($tempImg, "$newPath/$img", $quality) or die("Cant save image");

        // Clean up.
        imagedestroy($original);
        imagedestroy($tempImg);
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        echo "oc";
        return false;
    }
}
```

when calling this function it showing black screen.i am displaying echo statement before and after

```
$original = imagecreatefromjpeg($path);
```

it shows only first echo statement second echo statement not displaying.What is the problem.

Comment: what does `echo $path;` prints? Is it valid JPG file?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `if (file_exists($path)) echo 'file exists!';` just after the `echo $path;` line.

//edit:

So it exists, does `if (function_exists('imagecreatefromjpeg')) echo 'function exists';` also echo something?

Otherwise it could be a problem with right filetype or something I read on http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromjpeg.php, it says that certain canon powershots let this function crash.

Also, is your error reporting on? Try adding `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` to the beginning of the script.

Comment: In that case, the php you are using does not have support for image handling. If your server is running ubuntu, this should do the trick: `sudo apt-get install php5-gd`

Comment: my php version is  5.3.2-1ubuntu4.9

Comment: Do you have ssh access to the server? If so, you can use the code provided. Otherwise, you should contact your hosting company with the request of adding the `gd-library` for image manipulation.

Comment: No i am not having access permission